# How can i align one div in to middle?

Tags: html, css, alignment

```css
html,body {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  }

#side-bar{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:15%;
  height:100%; 
  float:left;
}
#content{
  border:1px solid green;
  width:50%;
  height:6%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div id="side-bar">
    <div id ="content"></div>
  </div>
  
    
</body>
```

Here is My code ,I'm trying to align the  #content part in to middle of side bar,I'm tried the following thinks.

```
#side-bar{ align-content : center; }
```

and then

```
#content{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
```

but both are not worked for Me,how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to center a div would be to use `margin: 0 auto;`. See [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) for centering with CSS.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#side-bar {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50%;
  height: 6%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="side-bar">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only Using     `margin: 0 auto;` in **#content**

```css
html,body {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  }

#side-bar{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:15%;
  height:100%; 
  float:left;
}
#content{
  border:1px solid green;
  width:50%;
  height:6%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div id="side-bar">
    <div id ="content"></div>
  </div>
  
    
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need ah **center** of `#content` apply `margin:auto`.

if need ah **middle** on on both vertical and horizontal apply with `position:relative;top:47%` also.If you no need just remove that

```css
html,body {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  }

#side-bar{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:15%;
  height:100%; 
  float:left;
}
#content{
  position:relative;/*for both vertical and horizontal center*/
  border:1px solid green;
  margin:auto;/*for center*/
  top:47%;/*for both vertical and horizontal center*/
  width:50%;
  height:6%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div id="side-bar">
    <div id ="content"></div>
  </div>
  
    
</body>
```

Comment: what padding:auto does?

Comment: @WhiteMaskers No need apply padding.i was just added  .see the updated answer